# Как развернуть postgres_exporter в докере и поключить к prometheus

Tags: postgresql, prometheus, grafana

У меня есть сервер на Debian 8, в котором установлен docker. Подход нужен в контейнерах. В контейнер установлен postgres 9.6. Хочу настроить сбор данных таблицы pg_stat_statements в prometheus через postgres_exporter из PostgreSQL, а потом смотреть на график через grafana. Разворачивание grafana и Prometheus делал по инструкции:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom
$ cd dockprom
$ docker-compose up -d
```

[Отсюда](https://habr.com/company/southbridge/blog/314212/). В настройках prometheus.yml добавил:

```
- job_name: 'postgres-exporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9187']
```

Но проблема с подключением postgres-exporter:
 [image: Prometheus targets status]

Брал вот этот экспортет статистики для PostgreSQL: [ссылка](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter). Его пробовал разворачивать в docker с разными портами, вариантами, но Prometheus ни как не хотел его подцеплять. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно все это дело настроить?

Comment: Я думаю правильным будет всё же единый docker-compose.yml в котором будут прописаны все сервисы.